# Application.Goto Run-Time Error 5

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have been an active user of the information on this site and it has generally served me very well. I am struggling with this one however... I built an excel document a while back with this code:
Application.Goto Range("PART_NUMBERS").Cells(Application.Match(ROP_UPDATE.Label5.Caption, Range("PART_NUMBERS"), 0))

and it works beautifully! Basically it checks to see if a checkmark on a userform is checked and if it is it then finds the label associated with that checkmark and it finds it in a range where i can use other lines of code to do stuff. anyway... I am building another document where i need to do essentially the same thing and i built the code accordingly:

Application.Goto Range("po_s").Cells(Application.Match(PO_Checker.Label1.Caption, Range("po_s"), 0))

it gives me run-time error 5 every time. Identical code basically and i have looked over my named ranges and changed them a few times. I am stumped. Why does this code work good on my first document but not the one i am working on now? both are macro enabled. Any suggestions help. Thank you!

Comment: What do you get with a `debug.print Application.Match(PO_Checker.Label1.Caption, Range("po_s"), 0)` ? (within the worksheet's private code sheet)

Comment: i put this into the private worksheet code                                                              "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()
Debug.Print Application.Match(PO_Checker.Label1.Caption, Range("po_s"), 0)
End Sub"                                                                                                                   I then get a "compile error:     procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: ... and what was in the VBE's Immediate window after you did that?

Comment: it just opened VBA and highlighted :Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange()  in blue